# C++98 convert vector elements to class function arguments?

Tags: function, parameters, arguments, stdvector, c++98

I was wondering if this is possible in C++98? I know that it can be done since C++11 using variadic templates, tuples and applying a tuple to a function. But can C++98 do the same, even if it requires some extra work, maybe using boost libraries but only version 1.39?

Let's say that I have a vector of strings:

```
std::vector<string> vec = {"A","B"};
```

and this function:

```
void f(string a, string b)
{
    //... do something with a and b
}

//I know that i can pass the vector like this:
void f(const vector<string>& v)
{
    //... do something with v
}
```

But I don't want to do it like that. I want to declare my functions with normal arguments, but be able to expand a vector into function parameters. And it needs to work with C++98, not C++11.

Comment: 'But I don't wanna do like that I want to declare my functions with normal arguments. But be able to expand a vector into function parameters.' What? Can you rephrase, I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: I mean that i don't want to declare the function using vector as argument. instead I want it to be declared normally like the first function above, but being able to apply parameters from a vector to the function. Or maybe as boost::tuple I don't know whatever is better for this situation

Comment: What's wrong with using `void f(const vector<string>& v) { f(v[0], v[1]); }` ?